# java - Solr localhost:8983 Not Found

Tags: java, solr

I am new to solr. Following the tutorial from [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/tutorial.html) i Can't Get Past Step 2 in the Tutorial. After running `java -jar start.jar` and  then connecting to `http://localhost:8983/solr/`

i get this error page which says:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Not Found

Powered by Jetty://
```

I changed the port from 8983 to 8080 but the problem persisted.
On running ant `ant example` i get this error message `build.xml does nto exist`

I am working with windows 7 and the downloaded version of solr is solr-4.9.0.zip.

Comment: Says it's not found... where is your WWW root?

Comment: If you go to /, you should see a list of the registered contexts. If this is empty, include that information in the question - if it's there (and maybe under another name than Solr, click it). Are you running `java -jar start.jar` from the examples directory directly?

Comment: @fiskfisk yes i am running java -jar start.jar right in the examples directory.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the log, do you see any registeretd contexts, etc?

Comment: There was an issue with jre...re installation with older version did the job...

Comment: This seems to happen if the "wrong" Java version is used to start Solr. I requested https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10650 to improve that solr no longer makes a secret out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check wheather the port(8983) is already in use or not. You can start solr in alternate port(like 4983) by using the following command

**java -Djetty.port=4983 -jar start.jar**

And now hit your browser with your doamin name or localhost:port as shown below:

http://yourdoamin.com:4983/solr

If you are still unable to start solr ,then solr log at the follwoing path
../solr-4.9.0/example/logs

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your solr.log?

Also when you start the solr with: **java -Djetty.port=4983 -jar start.jar**
Are you able to see server started in the console from where you are executing this?

How are you changing jetty port in solr? Through commands i mentioned above or by changing jetty.xml.

Note: changing port in jetty.xml dont work properly.